# Sharepoint errror accessing files and opening directories in explorer

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office

IT replaced my machine with a more powerful one (same OS Windows 7 64 bit Pro) and I no longer can open any MS Office files from Sharepoint. They provide Office 2010 so no solutions from 2013 apply.

When I click on any Word, Excel or PP document in Sharepoint, the corresponding application starts up, but does not open a document. Instead it throws the following error:

[image]

Title: Microsoft Word Security Warning

Message: Certificate Error

Description: The application experienced an internal error loading the SSL libraries.

Button: OK

If instead of opening a file I go to Libraries view and click on Open With Explorer button, another window pops up 3 times regardless of OK or Cancel:

[image]

Title: Select Certificate

The list contains a 2-way SSL cert which every developer has to install in order to debug one of our applications, and one of my co-worker's certificate. My certificate is not in the list, and that co-worker never used this machine.

Buttons: OK, Cancel, View Certificate

Finally it asks for my credentials again and pops up this:

[image]

The IT is not very confident troubleshooting this problem so I am on my own.

Tried solutions from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f455169-dc6a-48ed-b667-ae11dd3d4707/your-client-does-not-support-opening-this-list-with-windows-explorer?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) but none worked. If I disable any sharepoint and grove add-ons in IE, I can download the file fine, but have no way to upload back. Any non-office file opens fine in IE.

Comment: You should be contacting your company internal support desk. This is a configuration issue within their network that you should not have the access to change.

Comment: How is that that any question about Microsoft products not working gets automatically downvoted? Not enough billion$ for you?

Comment: It's because this is **server**fault, not **workstation**fault.

Comment: Wow, eloquent, are we? Sharepoint runs on a server. And GPO comes from a server. So this question had the server related root cause and solution. Boo.

Comment: Yes, and if the persons in charge of the server had asked it, it would have been on topic. In this instance, you're a workstation user, not a server administrator. If you don't have the ability to check and/or change the server config, view the logs, etc, then this site isn't the one you need. (There are a **lot** of Microsoft questions here; the ones that are on-topic and well written according to  [How do I ask a good question](//serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) don't get downvoted.

Comment: Self appointed moderator alert!

Comment: I do beg your pardon; I mistook your first comment for a request for further information. My apologies for wasting your time by explaining things you are clearly uninterested in, such as what this site is actually for.

Comment: This question is very off topic for Compose. Please review our FAQ and refrain from repeat performances.

Comment: Thank you folks for taking time out of your busy lives to eradicate sarcasm. It has no place on the Internet, where every statement must be strictly regulated by policies. One day you will get a medal for saving the Internet from another 374 character post, I am sure! Keep up good work. @JennyD I upvoted your comment as it's spot on - completely uninterested in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The admin found and altered a GPO which was pushing a wrong TLS setting down. Once the registry key for TLS was altered on the machine, and the change persisted, the issue was fixed.

Comment: Wow, what a horrible answer. Too bad it solved the issue!